# What is the best way to update downloaded HLS files in iOS app?

Tags: avfoundation, http-live-streaming, avassetdownloadurlsession

I'm working on an iOS app. I implemented downloading HLS video files logic. I use `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`, `AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask`, `URLSessionConfiguration.background` for it.

I need to implement the logic to update HLS files if they were updated on the server. Is it possible to do this with [NSURLRequest.CachePolicy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/useprotocolcachepolicy)? Or are there other ways to do this?
Any help is appreciated.

Session configuration:

```
private let assetSessionConfiguration: URLSessionConfiguration = {
    let configurationIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "identifier"
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: configurationIdentifier)
    configuration.networkServiceType = .video
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        configuration.allowsExpensiveNetworkAccess = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let memoryMBAmount = 10
        let diskMBAmount = 2048
        configuration.urlCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: memoryMBAmount * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: diskMBAmount * 1024 * 1024, directory: CustomURL)
    } else {
        configuration.urlCache = URLCache.shared
    }

    return configuration
}()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to set the `cache-control` HTTP header on your master playlist response.

Comment: Could we use it with AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask or we need make an additional request? Could you please show an example? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use it with AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask!

Comment: Hey! Could you please have a look on the session configuration? I tried but it doesn't work for me. What should I change?

Comment: `cache-control` is the HTTP header you must set. `requestCachePolicy` should have no bearing.